# GNUPLOT: How to use a function to decide the plot style

Tags: function, gnuplot

I have lots of series to draw in 1 plot. I want to decide the plot style/type according to the number of a series. Here is the example code of what I am aiming for:

```
title(i)=value(sprintf("title%i",i))
title1='x'
title2='x^2'
title3='x^3'
...

with(i)=value(sprintf("with%i",i))
with1='lines'
with2='points'
with3='boxes'
...

plot for [i=1:100] '-' title title(i) with with(i)
```

I have test the title() function works. But the with function does not work correctly.

Can you help me fix the code?

Or do you think there are other ways to achieve what I am aiming for?

Comment: I tried several approaches, but didn't succeed. Usually you need a macro for this kind of replacements: `set macros; style='with boxes'; plot x @style`. But that doesn't work in your case, because macros work with string variables (here `style`), but not with functions. I guess, you would need to generate the whole script with an external tool...

Comment: While, it seems not possible then? Is it possible to bypass the obstacle by using multiple plot? Is it possible to set the with types before the plot command? e.g. set with xxxx; plot yyyyy;@Christoph

Comment: Yes, you can use `set style data lines` and similar. So you could use `eval('set style data '.with(3))`, but with multiplot you'll get problems with the titles.

Comment: For the interested reader: There has been a feature-request about this by the OP, [#385 Use a variable/function (after "with") to determine the type of graph.](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/385/).

Comment: Would you be OK with just cycling through all the available line types? I was able to get something like this to work `plot for [n=0:20:1] '' index n-1 using 2:1 with linespoints pointtype n pointsize 0.5` where `pointtype n` just cycles through all the available point types.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to build a string of a plot command and then run this string:

```
p="plot x linewidth 1"
do for [i=1:10]{
    p=p.sprintf(", x+%d linewidth %d", i, i+1)
}


print p

eval(p)
```

The output of the print command is:

```
plot x linewidth 1, x+1 linewidth 2, x+2 linewidth 3, ...
```

and this is the resulting plot:

[image]

Depending on what you finally want, this might be something for you:

```
do for [i=1:10]{
    p=p.(i==1 ? "'myData.csv' with lines" : "")
    p=p.(i==2 ? "'myData.csv' with steps" : "")
    ...

}
```

However, this looks pretty ugly.