# GNUPLOT: what is difference between wxt and windows terminal?

Tags: windows, terminal, gnuplot

What is difference between wxt and windows terminal?

Are they both supported in Linux, Windows, and Mac?

Are there any other good terminals for displaying plots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `wxt` terminal uses the wxWidgets library, where the 'wxt' comes from. The actual
 drawing is done via cairo, a 2D graphics library, and pango, a library for
 laying out and rendering text (see `help wxt`). This terminal should work on all three OS.

`windows` uses the Windows GDI to draw and write text. This is available only for Windows.

Other interactive terminals are

- `X11`: requires an XServer. Works on Linux, Mac and Windows (with cygwin?)
- `aqua`: this is for Mac only, but I don't know the current status of the terminal (working or not)
- `qt`: The qt terminal is strongly beeing improved for the upcoming 5.0 version. Outstanding feature (in the development version) are an export function to export the current plot as pdf, svg or raster image without replotting, and a QtWidget which allows embedding gnuplot into Qt applications.

Which terminal is "good" depends on your requirements (speed, features, dependencies, OS, etc.)

Comment: The new qt is so attractive. It would be so good if the qt can output pdf as the same as it is displayed on the screen. Currently pdf and wxt terminal have different size and other terminal setting units. The same code ends up with different outputs on different terminals. @Christoph

Comment: Is the new version considering to allow using a function to decide the plot style? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743042/gnuplot-how-to-use-a-function-to-decide-the-plot-style

Comment: No, it is not. You can try it with a feature request http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/, but I don't know how much work it would be to implement this.